# substr not working? php

Tags: php

Unfortunately I can't point you to a live example. But I've got a form that submits a bunch of data to the database.

I retrieve the 'date' field with

```
genesis_custom_field('date')
```

and the output date is "mm/dd/yyyy" e.g., 02/19/2012

so shouldn't

```
echo substr(genesis_custom_field('date'), 0, 2) . '<-M<br />'
```

output "02"

instead, it's outputting the full date format, "02/19/2012".

**INTENTS AND PURPOSES**

for intents and purposes, here's the code sample.

```
// The Query
$reviews_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1');

// The Loop
while ( $reviews_query->have_posts() ) : $reviews_query->the_post();

echo substr(genesis_custom_field('date'), 0, 2) . '<-M<br />';

endwhile;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

with the intended output of

```
02<-M
```

but I'm getting

```
02/19/2012<-M
```

Comment: Post `var_dump( genesis_custom_field('date'));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `genesis_custom_field` actually echoes the value rather than return it which is why `substr` isn't working.  You are basically calling `substr` on a null value.

Instead use the function `genesis_get_custom_field` if you want the value returned so you can modify it.

Comment: Oh God, thank you! I was wondering why it was appearing null when it obviously had a value! Just a misinterpretation of functions, thanks! Will accept in 5 minutes :)

Comment: FYI: `ob_start(); genesis_custom_field(...); $value = ob_get_clean();` - works with *any* function that is outputting instead of returning.